# Python executable for every operating system

Tags: python, operating-system, executable

i'm looking for a solution to convert a normal python file to an executable program for linux, macos, windows, ios, andriod and so on. Is there a way to do this? Best by a piece of python code?

Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: well you can use pyinstaller to compile it each time on different machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tool called `pyinstaller` you can find here [Link](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) with which you can accomplish that.

However, you need to compile it for the different OS after each update.

Also take a look at this thread, where options are explained in more detail and background reading is provided [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235123/python-executables-py2exe-or-pyinstaller)