# I'm writting a code to help my Valorant team track their kill and deaths using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, console, executable

I wrote this code:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, nick, positon, kills, deaths, jogos):
        print( "Computando jogador ... {}".format( self ) )
        self.__nick = nick
        self.__positon = positon
        self.__kills = kills
        self.__deaths = deaths
        self.__jogos = jogos
        self.__KDR = (self.__kills / self.__deaths)

    def player_info(self):
        kdr = (self.__kills / self.__deaths)
        print( "Jogador: {} \nPosição: {} \nFicou com o KD de {}/{}, em um total de {} jogos".format( self.__nick,
                                                                                                      self.__positon,
                                                                                                      self.__kills,
                                                                                                      self.__deaths,
                                                                                                      self.__jogos ),
               '\n'
               "KDR: {:1.2f}".format( kdr ) )

    def add_games(self, valor):
        self.__jogos += valor

    def add_kills(self, valor):
        self.__kills += valor

    def add_deaths(self, valor):
        self.__deaths += valor

    def add_kd(self, valor1, valor2, valor3):
        self.__kills += valor1
        self.__deaths += valor2
        self.__jogos += valor3

    def take_kills(self, valor):
        self.__kills -= valor

    def take_deaths(self, valor):
        self.__deaths -= valor

    def take_games(self, valor):
        self.__jogos -= valor

    def save(self):
        kdr = (self.__kills / self.__deaths)
        kdr = round( kdr, 2 )
        str(kdr)
        print( str( kdr ) )
        fd = open( 'KDR.txt', "w" )
        fd.write( "Jogador: {} \nPosição: {} \nFicou com o KD de {}/{}, em um total de {} jogos".format(self.__nick, self.__positon, self.__kills, self.__deaths, self.__jogos)
                  +'\n' "KDR: " + str(kdr))
```

I want to make an executable that can stores the self.player_info() output in a textfile called KDA.txt
But I don't know any way that I could run the code as a console but using a .exe archive.
Sorry if something here was wrong, I'm a 15 years old Brazilian, so if something is wrong and you want to help me i would be glad

Comment: Why not use [pyinstaller or py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235123/python-executables-py2exe-or-pyinstaller)?

Comment: I allways run this code in a python console, so wouldn't it be a problem if I just use the pyinstaller?

Comment: Okay I understand. Well in that case I'm not 100% sure, but writing a GUI or text based interface would definitely work.