# How to make any python program run standalone

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I make a python program run without python installed (like blender)? Is it includes liblaries to the program itself (Am I need to run "pip install which liblaries used" before running the program)? And how can i make this for a program with multiple scripts?

Comment: What you are looking for are tools that embed a script, required modules and a Python interpretor in a native executable program like PyInstaller of py2exe. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6235123/3545273)

Comment: In which Operating System?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use autopytoexe for windows applications.
It has GUI and you can save the compile settings.

https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/

Answer (score 0):

I don't have personal experience with this, but, as noted it the comments, it appears these are the tools that will do what you want.

Windows: https://pypi.org/project/py2exe/

MacOS: https://pypi.org/project/py2app/

Cross-platform: https://pypi.org/project/cx-Freeze/

Answer (score 0):

If you are the one who did the programming, and want your program to run on a system (with or without python installed), you can convert your initial python file into an executable, that is, files with the `.exe` extension.

## TO CONVERT - Open your Terminal:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

After installing `pyinstaller`, type in: `pyinstaller --onefile your_python_file.py`. This will convert your file to an executable. CAVEAT: If your file will use a terminal, then put a `-w` after `--onefile`, if it is graphical, then don't. After the conversion, you can see a `dist folder`, it contains your `.exe` file. Try running your file then, and see if it runs with no error.